# Making onEdit() faster and more efficient

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

After several googling, I arrived with a code that looks into a main sheet and shows or hides sheets *(named A to N)* depending on what checkbox is ticked/unticked *(main requirement)*.

However, it seems to be not that efficient, and takes a couple of seconds to truly show/hide the sheets after ticking/unticking their respective checkboxes. I've recently learned that `onEdit()` always runs whenever there's an Edit anywhere in the spreadsheet.

I would like to seek advise if it is possible to only run `onEdit()` when edits are done only on specific ranges, specifically **B6:B20 of Main** sheet *(which contains my checkboxes)*. Likewise, instead of going over all checkboxes and showing/hiding sheets based on what is ticked/unticked, is it possible for `onEdit()` to detect what was immediately ticked/unticked from among the checkboxes and show/hide the appropriate sheet? We maybe adding several other sheets in the future, and it will just get more inefficient if we try to scale the current code.

**Here's the code:**

```
function onEdit(e) {

var sheet = e.source.getSheetByName("Main");
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var A = ss.getSheetByName("A");
var B = ss.getSheetByName("B");
var C = ss.getSheetByName("C");
var D = ss.getSheetByName("D");
var E = ss.getSheetByName("E");
var F = ss.getSheetByName("F");  
var G = ss.getSheetByName("G");
var H = ss.getSheetByName("H");
var I = ss.getSheetByName("I");
var J = ss.getSheetByName("J");
var K = ss.getSheetByName("K");
var L = ss.getSheetByName("L");
var M = ss.getSheetByName("M");
var N = ss.getSheetByName("N");  

if(sheet.getRange('B6').getValue() === true){A.showSheet();}else{A.hideSheet();}
if(sheet.getRange('B7').getValue() === true){B.showSheet();}else{B.hideSheet();}
if(sheet.getRange('B8').getValue() === true){C.showSheet();}else{C.hideSheet();}
if(sheet.getRange('B9').getValue() === true){D.showSheet();}else{D.hideSheet();}
if(sheet.getRange('B10').getValue() === true){E.showSheet();}else{E.hideSheet();}
if(sheet.getRange('B11').getValue() === true){F.showSheet();}else{F.hideSheet();}
if(sheet.getRange('B12').getValue() === true){G.showSheet();}else{G.hideSheet();}
if(sheet.getRange('B13').getValue() === true){H.showSheet();}else{H.hideSheet();}
if(sheet.getRange('B14').getValue() === true){I.showSheet();}else{I.hideSheet();}
if(sheet.getRange('B15').getValue() === true){J.showSheet();}else{J.hideSheet();}
if(sheet.getRange('B17').getValue() === true){K.showSheet();}else{K.hideSheet();}
if(sheet.getRange('B18').getValue() === true){L.showSheet();}else{L.hideSheet();}
if(sheet.getRange('B19').getValue() === true){M.showSheet();}else{M.hideSheet();}
if(sheet.getRange('B20').getValue() === true){N.showSheet();}else{N.hideSheet();}
}
```

Likewise, here's a preview of our **Main sheet**. Based on the image, sheets B, E, J and K should be showing while the others should be hidden:

[image]

Comment: Please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices?hl=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onEdit will fire anytime the sheet is edited, however, you can reference the event object (e) to determine which cell was modified, and only take action if the edit is on a cell you actually care about.

I would do this by creating a map of cells to sheets, so you don't need a bunch of if statements, but rather just check if the cell is mapped and take action if it is.

```
var actionable_cell_map = {'B6':'A',
                           'B7':'B',
                           ...
                           'B20':'N'
                          };
function onEdit(e){
    if(e.range.getSheet().getName() == "Main"){
       var edited_cell = e.range.getA1Notation();
       if(actionable_cell_map[edited_cell]){
         var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(actionable_cell_map[edited_cell]);
         if(e.range.getValue() === true){
            sheet.showSheet();
         }else{
            sheet.hideSheet();
         }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: How about adding the condition for checking whether the sheet of the edited cell is `Main` to the if statement?

Comment: Thanks @cameron-roberts and @Tanaike. I've included an `IF` just before `var edited_cell = e.range.getA1Notation();` to return in case the source of object e doesn't match the "Main" sheet name.

Comment: Good catch @Tanaike I will update this answer to include the sheet check